# How to access USB port using pySerial (Windows)?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, usb, pyserial

I am trying to open USB port in Python (using pySerial). I ran port listing tool, but it only shows COM ports. I'd like to open USB port instead (trying to communicate with tablet, but that's not relevant, I suppose). I know it is possible (and quite easy) on Linux, but I am on Windows 8, so there's nothing like "/dev/tty...".

I'd like to show you some of my code, but I can't, because I have none yet (I need to know how to open USB port to be able to start coding, I am just testing yet).

Maybe I will have to install some other module, but I'd rather just stay with pySerial, if it's possible.

Can anyone help me with opening USB port?

Comment: If your device is truly using serial communication, it should bind to one of the serial (COM) ports. Have you tried connecting to each of the ports in your port listing tool?

Comment: If you are trying to connect to a tablet and the tablet does not connect to the computer as a virtual COM device then pyserial won't be able to connect to it. Maybe check out pyusb.