# serial USB port number on window (as parameter)

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, usb, pyusb

I want to connect with a USB stick (ANT+ suntoo) for serial communication using under python USB libraries in eclipse under windows 8.1. I have to pass the serial address of my USB stick(Port_#0001.Hub_#0003) as a parameter to my python program.

In linux it would be as: #SERIAL = '/dev/ttyUSB0', so nothing like this in window

However in windows it will some variant of COMx, but my OS do't display the USB as COM port. Rather It just displays Generic USB HUB with Port and hub number.

I tried to just pass COM3 but the error I am getting is as:
could not open port 'COM3': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

These questions [Qs01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413164/how-to-access-usb-port-using-pyserial-windows), [Qs02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457448/getting-usb-serial-port-parameters) are related but no avail. 
Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are referring to the suunto HR belt. I'm not sure what type of output cables they have. One way to do it is by using a serial to USB adapter cable that makes it a 'COM' Port. [Here](https://www.sabrent.com/product/SBT-USC1M/usb-serial-cable-adapter/) is an example. But make sure you install the drivers for the adapter. After you install the drivers and connect the cable, you'll see the COM port under Ports in Device Manager.Hope this helps!

Comment: Add the relevant content from the link to the body of your answer.

Comment: @GrantMiller The link is an image of the adapter cable. It's a serial DB-9 to USB adapter. I don't think there's anymore relevant content in that link. I included it to give the OP an idea of what the cable looks like.